# Problems in my first Cocos2d application for iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-iphone-2.x

I'm a beginner of iOS and Cocos2d. I've just integrated Cocos2d 2.1 with xcode 4.2 and using mac os 10.7.3. Just created my first sample application for Cocos2d and I've not written any single line of code but showing error. The errors are like..

[image]
[image]

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

So that's Cocos2D code that's not compiling?

It looks like they forgot to `#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>` or one of their own header files.
Is this a release version of the code?

Comment: Although #import <CoreText/CoreText.h> is integrated default, but still showing error.

Comment: Have you tried building against the iOS6/7 simulator?

Comment: It's iPhone 5.0 Simulator.